# why am i not able to return the Dataframe for this scala code

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

```
def csvReader(readCsvdf:DataFrame):Dataframe= {

   val readCsvDf= spark.read
      .format("csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .load("C:\\Users\\1591532\\Downloads\\xyz.csv").toDF()


}
```

Comment: put readCsvDf as the final line or eliminate the "val readCsvDf"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are assigning a value, which returns `unit`. In scala the return is the last line, so a unit type here, and not a df.

```
def csvReader(path: String)(implicit spark: SparkSession): Dataframe= {
   spark.read
      .format("csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .load(path)
}
```